# touchesEnded not called when UIView is over UIView

Tags: ios, swift, touch

- I have a UIViewController
- I have 2 UIViews
- first UIView is displayed over the entire screen.
- second UIView is displayed only in the upper half of the screen and over the first one.

When touching on the lower part (only on the first UIView), touchesBegan is called and after that touchesEnded. -> ok.

When touching the second UIView, then touchesBegan  is called, but touchesEnded is not called -> NOT ok

When removing the second UIView and touching the upperpart of the first UIView also both tocuhes Methods are called -> ok.

Does someone has an idea/hint for me where to search for the case where touchesEnded is not called ?

**Update**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        let worldmaprect=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, worldmapHeigth);
        worldmapview = Worldmapview(frame: worldmaprect);
        view.addSubview(worldmapview); // first UIView

        let statusbarrect=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 100);
        statusbar=StatusBar(frame: statusbarrect);
        view.addSubview(statusbar); //second UIVIew
```

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how you are creating and adding the views?

Comment: I added my code, where I add the 2 UIViews. I went through the code again and I couldn't detect anything special. My first question is : Should touchesEnded be called in this situation, when I click on the second UIView ?

Comment: Where are you creating the yearBarView?

        view.addSubview(yearbarview); //second UIVIew

Comment: That was wrong. I corrected the code. It was after just renaming.,

Comment: Are you sure `touchesEnded` is not being called? Doesn't matter which view are you touching, `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` should always be called.

Comment: Sorry to all. I made a misstake, but I don't know what. I just started from scratch with my ViewController. Copied all nessessary stuff into the new one and it worked. I can't tell what it was. Sorry for wasting your time. I will delete this question, because it doesn't help anyone.